# I can't seem to get my C program to take inputs (Rectangular Prism Calculator)

Tags: c, math

This is my first time posting so I couldn't get the code to post directly into the text box.

The problem I was having is that it generates numbers automatically instead of prompting the user for inputs.  I am new to C so I don't quite understand what I am doing wrong.  Thanks in advance.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



//function prototype
int getLength();
int getWidth();
int getHeight();

int vol (int, int, int);
int sA(int, int, int);
void disp(int, int);
int main()
{
    //declarations

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int volume = 0;
    int surfaceArea = 0;
    //input

    //calculation

    volume = vol(a, b, c);
    surfaceArea = sA(a, b, c);
    a = getLength;
    b = getWidth;
    c = getHeight;
    //output
    disp(vol,surfaceArea);
    return 0;
}//end main

//get length
int getLength()
{

    int length = 0;
    printf("enter length:  ");
    scanf("%d", &length);
    return length;
}


//get width
int getWidth()
{
    int width = 0;
    printf("enter width:  ");
    scanf("%d", &width);
    return width;
}

int getHeight()
{
    int height = 0;
    printf("enter height:  ");
    scanf("%d", &height);
    return height;
}
int vol(length, width, height)
{
    //return a * b * c
    int volume = 0;
    volume = (length * width * height);
    return volume;

}//end volume

int sA(length, height, width)
{
    //declare variables

    int wL1 = 0;
    int wL2 = 0;
    int wL3 = 0;
    int surfaceArea = 0;
    //breaking up into small portions
    wL1 = (width*length);
    wL2 = (height*length);
    wL3 = (height*width);
    surfaceArea = 2*(wL1+wL2+wL3);
    //return A=2(wl+hl+hw)
    return surfaceArea;

}//end surface area

void disp(volume,surfaceArea)
{
    //display results
    printf("The Volume of the Rectangular Prism is:   %d \n\n", volume );
    printf("The Surface Area of the Rectangular prism is:  %d", surfaceArea);
}
```

Comment: I think since you're new here, you want to take a 2min tour, how this site works: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: This (`int vol(length, width, height)`) as your function definition is using the very sloppy pre-standard rules for function definitions.  It implicitly types each of the various arguments as of type `int`.  That was disallowed in C99.  It was allowed in C89/C90 out of simple necessity; at the time, there was a lot of old code with that type of definition, but that was almost 25 years ago.  Any new code you write should be written to a more modern standard.  You should be adding options to your compiler to get more warnings, and you should be paying attention to what it says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to change this:

```
//Line 18
volume = vol(a, b, c);
surfaceArea = sA(a, b, c);
a = getLength;
b = getWidth;
c = getHeight;

//Line 33
disp(vol,surfaceArea);

//Line 64
int vol(length, width, height)

//Line 73
int sA(length, height, width)

//Line 91
void disp(volume, surfaceArea)
```

to this:

```
//Line 18
a = getLength();
           //^^Call the function and assign the value before you call functions with this variable
b = getWidth();
c = getHeight();
volume = vol(a, b, c);
surfaceArea = sA(a, b, c);

//Line 33
disp(volume, surfaceArea);
   //^^^^^^ vol doesn't exists i think you wanted to use volume

//Line 64
int vol(int length, int width, int height)
      //^^^ Declare the type of the variable, like in your prototype

//Line 73
int sA(int length, int height, int width)

//Line 91
void disp(int volume,int surfaceArea)
```

Comment: I changed everything to be like you have it and I am still not returning anything for my surface area and volume.  Any ideas?

Comment: @ArcaneZorro You can copy the entire code here: http://ideone.com/35yl1c . I think you forgot to change the order from the variable assignment and the disp call

Comment: @Rizier123 Thank you for your help.  For some reason I had it it my head that in most circumstances you could use int in place of the variable name.  I'm used to python and having to use int at all is foreign to me.

Comment: @ArcaneZorro You're welcome! Have a nice day :D (Don't know anything about python)

Answer (score 0):

```
When calling a function, 
even a function with no parameters, 
the parens, after the function name are required.

also, using the following as an example, 
the code needs to check the returned value from calls to scanf() 
to assure the input/conversion operation was successful.

int getHeight()
{
    int height = 0;
    printf("enter height:  ");

    // note: leading space ' ' in format string
    //       to consume any left over white space, (like a newline)
    if( 1 != scanf(" %d", &height) )
    { // then scanf failed
        perror( "scanf for height failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    return height;
} // end function: getHeight
```